# Partner STS returned a wst:RequestFailed error

Tags: c#, sharepoint-online, csom

I have a C# application that is accessing SharePoint online lists via the SharePoint CSOM SDK.
The below mentioned code **randomly** fails and throws the above the Partner STS error.

I have tried using the Async method call and setting DisableReturnValueCache to true on the client context.

```
var o365Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(SystemConfiguration.Sharepoint.AuthUser, o365SecurePassword);

var o365Context = new ClientContext(SystemConfiguration.Sharepoint.Url);
o365Context.Credentials = o365Credentials;
o365Context.DisableReturnValueCache = true;

// and while accessing list items :

CamlQuery queryList = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();

ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(queryList);

// Retrieve all items in the ListItemCollection from List.GetItems(Query). 
context.Load(listItems, items => items.Include(
    item => item.FieldValuesAsText,
    item => item.DisplayName)
);

if (context.HasPendingRequest)
{
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I expect the code to consistently fetch List items without random failures.
Please help! Thanks

Comment: Now, this issue has become more frequent. Happening almost 50% of the times. Can someone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So due to lack of response on this question, and any knowledge on GitHub or Other Microsoft Forums, I finally moved from Using SharePoint-CSOM to Microsoft Graph API for managing SharePoint lists.

And in my opinion, I have seen a significant improvement in performance and now my connection to Graph can be Singleton with regular Token Refreshes.

Thanks!